May I implement a classmethod calling instance attributes?
I need a class function which creates a new instance from existing instance attributes.
This seems to me to be a factory function (hence the thought that it could be a class method), but it needs the class to be instanced.
Should/may I use the @classmethod decorator?
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Coin:
  obverse: str
  reverse: str

  def flip(self):
      return Coin(self.reverse, self.obverse)


cent = Coin('cent_ob', 'cent_rev')
flipped_cent = cent.flip()

cent
Out[20]: Coin(obverse='cent_ob', reverse='cent_rev')
flipped_cent
Out[21]: Coin(obverse='cent_rev', reverse='cent_ob')

This works. But if I use the decorator, it does not.
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Coin:
  obverse: str
  reverse: str

  @classmethod
  def flip(cls, self):
      return cls(self.reverse, self.obverse)

cent = Coin('cent_ob', 'cent_rev')
flipped_cent = cent.flip()

TypeError: Coin.flip() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

What case am I dealing with here? Is there another decorator more suited to this case?
My primary goal is more to have a decorator explicitly indicating "hey, you have a factory function here".

Why do you want this to be a class method?

if you want this to be a class method, then you need to pass in the instance explicitly, something like cent.flip(cent), or more reasonably since it is a classmethod, use Coin.flip(cent), but it looks like you just want an instance method here.

XYProblem (Why do you want a class method when an instance method would work correctly?)

Class methods don't get an instance unless you pass it explicitly. Just as the first cent.flip() is equivalent to Coin.flip(cent), the second one is equivalent to Coin.flip(Coin). Only the type of cent is passed to the method.

The name flip implies mutation: the current coin gets flipped. A name like flipped would better imply a new coin, but in a different state, is returned.

No need to make it a classmethod, as the state of one Coin doesn't necessarily need to be the state of all the coins you create. Do this instead:
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Coin:
  obverse: str
  reverse: str

  def flip(self):
      return Coin(self.reverse, self.obverse)


cent = Coin('cent_ob', 'cent_rev')
flipped_cent = cent.flip()

Now, if you envision to have only one instance of this class in your code, then simply change the state of that singleton. You can even stop worrying about strings and simply store one variable that indicates whether the coin is flipped opposite to its initial state:
@dataclass
class Coin:
    flipped = 0
    
    def flip(self):
        self.flipped = 1 & (self.flipped + 1)

Test with this:
coin = Coin()
print(coin.flipped)
coin.flip()
print(coin.flipped)
coin.flip()
print(coin.flipped)
coin.flip()
print(coin.flipped)

Finally, a side comment: sometimes, especially in board games, to "flip a coin" means to toss it in the air and give it a new state at random. Perhaps you may want to call this method something like turn_over or similar. Up to you.
